# who makes an LED desktop monitor besides Apple?

Tags: display, product-rec, led, backlight

Besides Apple (Cinema Display) who sells an LED backlit computer display 1900 x 1200 or 1900 x 1080?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Samsung](http://www.engadget.com/2009/01/13/samsungs-led-backlit-p2370l-lcd-monitor-looks-good-for-399/),
[Dell](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/Monitors/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&cs=19&sku=320-7956)

Comment: Dell UltraSharp and HP's rock Apple.

Answer (score 2):

The [Dell G22](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?sku=320-7958&cs=04&c=us&l=en&dgc=BF&cid=7421&lid=197378&acd=10549103-3026717-9164__2_9__) is a 22inch backlit monitor with a resolution of 1680 by 1050 (which is a bit smaller than you requested). Dell monitors (unlike their computers) are fantastic and I would recommend them any day.

[image]

Alternatively, Samsung has their [Samsung  XL24](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824001265) which is 24 inches and has a resolution of 1920 by 1200